# google app engine python issues

Tags: python, google-app-engine, terminal

I am trying to use google app engine to create my own proxy for internet browsing, as my college blocks almost everything. Every time I try I end up with terminal sitting there for hours not doing anything and lagging my computer. If anyone can help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. Is it the fact that when it asks for a python command to launch I skip it? Please help and thanks in advance.

Terminal is doing this:

```
gcloud app deploy
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - test-proxy-151010/default/20161129t214424 (from [/Users/OliverPinel/app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://test-proxy-151010.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...failed.               
WARNING: We couldn't validate that your project is ready to deploy to App Engine Flexible Environment. If deployment fails, please check the following message and try again:
Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~test-proxy-151010'). Out of retries.  Last error: Temporary error occurred while verifying project: TEMPORARY_ERROR: Operation does not satisfy the following requirements: billing-enabled {Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'test-proxy-151010' to proceed., https://console.developers.google.com/project/test-proxy-151010/settings}
com.google.api.management.server.common.exceptions.ServiceManagementNonRetriableStorageException: Operation does not satisfy the following requirements: billing-enabled {Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'test-proxy-151010' to proceed., 
h ttps://console.developers.google.com/project/test-proxy-151010/settings}
    at com.google.api.management.server.integrations.usage.requirements.RequirementChecker.lambda$checkAllAsync$3(RequirementChecker.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:246)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture$TransformFuture.doTransform(AbstractTransformFuture.java:236)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractTransformFuture.run(AbstractTransformFuture.java:137)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:439)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:903)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:814)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:656)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.CollectionFuture$CollectionFutureRunningState.handleAllCompleted(CollectionFuture.java:81)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture$RunningState.processCompleted(AggregateFuture.java:245)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture$RunningState.decrementCountAndMaybeComplete(AggregateFuture.java:232)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture$RunningState.access$300(AggregateFuture.java:78)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AggregateFuture$RunningState$1.run(AggregateFuture.java:135)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:439)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:903)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:814)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:656)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.AbstractRpcFuture.success(AbstractRpcFuture.java:114)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:847)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:316)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.runCallback(RpcStub.java:885)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:895)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:874)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1243)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1140)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.loadbalancer.ReplicatedRpcChannel$InterceptedCallback.finishRpc(ReplicatedRpcChannel.java:1087)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.loadbalancer.ReplicatedRpcChannel$InterceptedCallback.rpcFinished(ReplicatedRpcChannel.java:949)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.loadbalancer.ReplicatedRpcChannel$InterceptedCallback.success(ReplicatedRpcChannel.java:911)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1243)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1140)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1676)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1491)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:3306)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:3045)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2900(RpcNetChannel.java:181)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:4254)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:688)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:463)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseOneMessage(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:889)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseMessages(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:766)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.access$400(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:47)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport$2.dataReceived(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:366)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.handleNetworkReadEvent(SocketConnection.java:1104)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.access$800(SocketConnection.java:47)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection$NetworkReadHandlerImpl.run(SocketConnection.java:1125)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1012)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1877)
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
WARNING: Deployment of App Engine Flexible Environment apps is currently in Beta
WARNING: Could not generate [source-context.json]: Could not list remote URLs from source directory: /Users/OliverPinel
Building and pushing image for service [default]
```

(then it does nothing)

Comment: this is unreadable

Comment: "Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'test-proxy-151010' to proceed." - looks like you have an un/misconfigured service (empty name) which triggers billing to be required for your app.